# How to run an exported QGIS program as a stand-alone application?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-python-console

I have a research partner who exported their QGIS algorithm to a python script, and my job is to use that Python file to create a web application that provides access to that algorithm.

My eventual workflow would look like this:

1. The user gives me several files on which the algorithm should operate.
2. I run the algorithm with those files as input
3. I send the resulting data back to the user for display/download

1 and 3 aren't too bad, those are web development problems. The second part is the hard one.

I'm stuck on figuring out how to do a few things:

1. Import qgis.core so that I can run the algorithm
2. The algorithm takes in a number of external files (.shp files and whatnot) as data, and I can't tell how exactly I'm supposed to feed them into the algorithm.
3. How to actually call the algorithm from the command line.

This script was build with QGIS's graphical editor, so it wasn't even originally written in Python. This is an automated export of the workflow he built.

My guess is that the script is meant to be run in the QGIS Python console, and so getting it to run on it's own in the server will take considerable plumbing, none of which I know how to do.

Does anybody have any experience doing anything like this?

The exported Python code just inherits from the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` class and then has it's own `initAlgorithm` and `processAlgorithm` methods. But none of them seem to describe where the file inputs should be coming from, and I don't know how to run the code.

Comment: Have you looked at the QPackage plugin?

Comment: The problem with that is I don't want to bundle the same data used in development, I want to feed in the files submitted by the user. It looks like Qpackage would help bundle my files and code, but it wouldn't show me how to dynamically load files into the algorithm. If I'm wrong please let me know, I'd love it if it worked.